# Can't seem to change default editor in OSX Lion terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-lion

I can't seem to change the default bash editor in OSX Lion terminal.

I've tried setting:

```
export EDITOR='<editor symlink with parameter>'
```

in both ~/.bashrc & ~/.bash_profile . The symlink is subl, and the parameter is -w.
from the prompt it is:

```
subl -w
```

I have restarted terminal after each but every time I enter:

```
edit test-file.md
```

it opens TextWrangler (not the editor I've set). I've tried opening the symlink from the command line with no problem. I realize that I should probably just get used to typing the symlink, but the anal side of me wants to know why I can't set the default editor.

Any help with this trivial problem would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not even sure what edit command is.  i don't have in on my Mac OS X Lion.  Whatever it is, sounds like it ignores the EDITOR env variable and uses your MacOS X application settings.
What you want can be accomplished with the alias shell command though:

```
alias edit=/path/to/vim
```

Comment: Thanks again, I didn't realize edit wasn't a command, obviously I'll need to put more time into studying my bash commands. :$

Comment: `edit` comes with TextWrangler. It is specific to TextWrangler, which is why you can't make it do something else.

Comment: @Ken, Ahh, now it makes more sense. Thanks for the input!